SQL, select by having duplicates in one column, but exclude if also 1:1 duplicate in other column
I need to select values from one column, that have duplicates, but exclude values, that also have duplicates in other column. Working with SQLite. Need query to be reasonably optimal.
Example table:



file
checksum




2
1


3
1


4
2


4
2


5
3


5
3


6
3


7
4


7
4


8
4


8
4


9
5


10
6



SQL:
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    file    INT,
    checksum    INT
);

INSERT INTO t1 (file, checksum) VALUES
    ('2', '1'),
    ('3', '1'),
    ('4', '2'),
    ('4', '2'),
    ('5', '3'),
    ('5', '3'),
    ('6', '3'),
    ('7', '4'),
    ('7', '4'),
    ('8', '4'),
    ('8', '4'),
    ('9', '5'),
    ('10', '6');

I end up with query:
select checksum from t1
         where file not in (select file from t1 group by file having count(file) > 1)
         group by checksum
         having count(checksum) > 1

But it dose not select checksum=3,4
Expected result is checksum = [1,3,4]
sqlfiddle

A [mcve] is supposed to also include the expected result.

I think this question could be helped by rewriting your first sentence to use actual column names from your sample data instead of "one column" and "other column".

If I understand correctly, I think just: select checksum from t1 group by checksum having count(distinct file) > 1 would do the trick. There's no reason to check if checksum is duplicate using this logic since it MUST be in order to have a count(distinct file) > 1.

You are filtering by file before you check for checksum totals.  It would be better to check for how many distinct files you have rather than filter them.
select checksum from t1
        group by checksum
        having count(DISTINCT file)>1;

I was able to get your desired result using sqlfiddle.

I was even able to implement it to Django ORM: Image.objects.values("checksum").annotate(cnt=Count("file", distinct=True)).filter(cnt__gt=1).all() - nice!

Dublicate checksum with not the same file
select checksum 
from (
   select distinct file, checksum 
   from t1 )
group by checksum
having count(checksum) > 1

